# How PSCI interface can be used to boot kernel in Hyp/EL2 mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, u-boot, armv7, arm64

I'm trying to understand how U-boot PSCI interface is used to boot kernel into HYP mode.

Going through u-boot source, I do see there is a generic psci.S and other psci.S which is board specific and have following doubts.

1). How and where psci.S fits in normal u-boot flow(when and how psci service like cpu_on and cpu_off is called while booting u-boot).s

2). How this psci interface of u-boot is used to boot kernel in HYP mode(what is it in psci interface that allow Linux   kernel to booted in HYP mode)?

Comment: There is no answer to this, because the question is invalid. U-boot, in its guise of also pretending to be firmware, _is the PSCI implementation_. It's akin to asking "how is the kernel's syscall interface used to start the init process at EL0?". In terms of power state coordination, the thing responsible for booting Linux in whatever mode it boots in is **initially applying power to the system** - the kernel itself has long booted by the time it gets to making PSCI calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have gone through this patch-set http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2013-December/168655.html which says it(PSCI interface in u-boot) help booting kernel in HYP mode . Hope you see my point now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1). How and where psci.S fits in normal u-boot flow

U-boot sets aside some secure-world memory and copies that secure monitor code there, so that it can stay resident after U-Boot exits and provide minimal handling of some PSCI `SMC` calls.

> (when and how psci service like cpu_on and cpu_off is called while booting u-boot)

They aren't. U-Boot runs and hands over to Linux on the primary CPU only. Linux may bring up secondary cores later in its own boot process, but U-Boot is long gone by then, except for the aforementioned secure monitor code.

> 2). How this psci interface of u-boot is used to boot kernel in HYP mode

It isn't.

> (what is it in psci interface that allow Linux kernel to booted in HYP mode)?

Nothing.

---

The point behind the patch series you refer to is that it was (and unfortunately still is) all too common for 32-bit ARM platforms to have TrustZone-aware hardware designs but crap software support. The vendor BSPs implement just enough bootloader to get the thing started, and never switch out of secure SVC mode from boot, so the whole of Linux runs in the secure world, and their kernel is full of highly platform-specific code poking secure-only hardware like the power controller directly. This poses a problem if you want to use virtualisation (which, if you're the KVM/ARM co-maintainer and have recently bought yourself a CubieTruck, is obviously a pressing concern...) - it's easy enough to take the U-boot code for such a platform and make it switch into NS-HYP before starting Linux, thus enabling KVM (upstream U-boot already had some rudimentary support for this at the time), but once you've dropped out of the secure world you can't then later bring up your secondary CPUs with the original `smp_operations` that depend on touching secure-only hardware.

By implementing some trivial runtime "firmware" hanging off the back of the bootloader, you then have the simplest way of calling back into the secure world as needed, and it makes the most sense to move the necessary platform-specific code there to abstract the operations away behind a simple firmware call interface, *especially* if there's already a suitable one supported by Linux.

There's absolutely nothing special about PSCI itself - there are plenty of ARM platforms that have proper secure firmware, with which they implement power management and SMP operations, but via their own proprietary protocol. The only vaguely relevant aspect is that conforming to the PSCI spec guarantees that the all CPUs are going to come up in the same mode, thus if you did initially enter Linux in HYP, you won't see mismatched secondaries coming up in some other incompatible mode or security state.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. It really helped. I have few follow up queries 1).  "you then have the simplest way of calling back into the secure world as needed" , By "firmware" you meant "PSCI"? I understand it has been done using "smc ,0#" but why we want to do it , is PSCI services runs only in EL3(I doubt on it) ? 2). With this patch series , primary CPU bring up happens through PSCI services?

Comment: PSCI is [just a _protocol_](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0022c/index.html) that firmware code can implement. In that context, "firmware" can also include hypervisors (usually by trapping a guest OS's `smc`, but there is provision in the spec for PSCI calls via `hvc` where EL3 is unimplemented). As I said before, primary CPU bringup happens by **turning the system on** - how exactly do you suppose a CPU could run code to install some exception vectors, issue a software call and run further code to power _itself_ up?